# Conditionally create an object in c++

Tags: c++, scope, heap-memory

I am writing a program that has the option to visualize the output of an algorithm I am working on - this is done by changing a `const bool VISUALIZE_OUTPUT` variable defined in a header file. In the main file, I want to have this kind of pattern:

```
if(VISUALIZE_OUTPUT) {
    VisualizerObject vis_object;
}
...
if(VISUALIZE_OUTPUT) {
    vis_object.initscene(objects_here);
}
...
if(VISUALIZE_OUTPUT) {
    vis_object.drawScene(objects_here);
}
```

However, this clearly won't compile since vis_object goes out of scope. I don't want to declare the object before the condition since it is a big object and it needs to available for multiple points in the code (I can't just have one conditional statement where everything is done).

What is the preferred way of doing this?

- Declare the object on the heap and refer to it by using a pointer (or
  unique_ptr)?
- Declare the object on the heap and make a reference to it
  since it won't ever change?
- Some other alternative?

Comment: Have you **measured** a performance problem with just having `VisualizerObject vis_object;` in the outermost scope it needs to be?

Comment: I think your desired "kind of pattern" is flawed - essentially, you're seeking a way to do things conditionally in a way that does not respect scope.   As such, a viable option would be to make `VISUALIZE_OUTPUT` a preprocessor macro, and wrap both the definition and usage of `vis_object` in `#ifdef VISUALISE_OUTPUT`/`#endif`.   This will work since the preprocessor does not respect scope.    However, bear in mind that use of preprocessor trickery is strongly discouraged in C++ for quite good reasons.

Answer (score 1):

A reference will not be useable here, because at declaration it should refere to an already existing object, and live in a scope englobing all your  `if(VISUALIZE_OUTPUT)`. Long story short, the object will have to be created unconditionally.

So IMHO a simple way would be to create it on the heap and use it through a pointer - do not forget do `delete` it when done. The good point is that the pointer could be initialized to `nullptr`, and so it could be unconditionnaly deleted.

But I think that the best way would be to encapsulate everything in an object created in highest scope. This object would then contain methods to create, use internally and finally destroy the actual `vis_object`. That way, if you do not need it, nothing will be actually instanciated, but the main procedure will not be cluttered with raw pointer processing.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Null_object_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern):

```
struct IVisualizerObject
{
    virtual ~IVisualizerObject() = default;
    virtual void initscene(Object&) = 0;
    virtual void drawScene(Object&) = 0;
    // ...
};

struct NullVisualizerObject : IVisualizerObject
{
    void initscene(Object&) override { /* Empty */ }
    void drawScene(Object&) override { /* Empty */}
    // ...
};

struct VisualizerObject : IVisualizerObject
{
    void initscene(Object& o) override { /*Implementation*/}
    void drawScene(Object& o) override { /*Implementation*/}
    // ...
};
```

And finally:

```
std::unique_ptr<IVisualizerObject> vis_object;
if (VISUALIZE_OUTPUT) {
    vis_object = std::make_unique<VisualizerObject>();
} else {
    vis_object = std::make_unique<NullVisualizer>();
}

// ...
vis_object->initscene(objects_here);

//...

vis_object->drawScene(objects_here);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give a few options.   All have upsides and downsides.

If it is NOT possible to modify `VisualizerObject`, as I noted in comments, the effect could be achieved by using the preprocessor, since the preprocessor does not respect scope, and the question specifically seeks controlling lifetime of an object in a manner that crosses scope boundaries.

```
#ifdef VISUALIZE_OUTPUT
   VisualizerObject vis_object;
#endif

#ifdef VISUALIZE_OUTPUT
    vis_object.initscene(objects_here);
#endif
```

The compiler will diagnose any usage of `vis_object` that are not in `#ifdef`/`#endif`.

The big criticism, of course, is that use of the preprocessor is considered poor practice in C++.   The advantage is that the approach can be used even if it is not possible to modify the `VisualizerObject` class (e.g. because it is in a third-party library without source code provided).

However, this is the only option that has the feature requested by the OP of object lifetime crossing scope boundaries.

If it is possible to modify the `VisualizerObject` class, make it a template with two specialisations

```
template<bool visualise> struct VisualizerObject
{
     // implement all member functions required to do nothing and have no members

     VisualizerObject() {};
     void initscene(types_here) {};    
};

template<> struct VisualizerObject<true>    // heavyweight implementation with lots of members
{
     VisualizerObject(): heavy1(), heavy2() {};
     void initscene(types_here) { expensive_operations_here();};

     HeavyWeight1 heavy1;
     HeavyWeight2 heavy2;
};

int main()
{
      VisualizerObject<VISUALIZE_OUTPUT> vis_object;
      ...
      vis_object.initscene(objects_here);
      ...
      vis_object.drawScene(objects_here);
}
```

The above will work in all C++ versions.   Essentially, it works by either instantiating a lightweight object with member functions that do nothing, or instantiating the heavyweight version.

It would also be possible to use the above approach to wrap a `VisualizerObject`.

```
 template<bool visualise> VisualizerWrapper
 {
      //  implement all required member functions to do nothing
      //   don't supply any members either
 }

 template<> VisualizerWrapper<true>
 {
      VisualizerWrapper() : object() {};

       //  implement all member functions as forwarders

     void initscene(types_here) { object.initscene(types_here);};

      VisualizerObject object;
 }

int main()
{
      VisualizerWrapper<VISUALIZE_OUTPUT> vis_object;
      ...
      vis_object.initscene(objects_here);
      ...
      vis_object.drawScene(objects_here);
}
```

The disadvantage of both of the template approaches is maintenance - when adding a member function to one class (template specialisation) it is necessary to add a function with the same signature to the other.   In large team settings, it is likely that testing/building will be mostly done with one setting of `VISUALIZE_OUTPUT` or the other - so it is easy to get one version out of alignment (different interface) to the other.    Problems of that (e.g. a failed build on changing the setting) are likely to emerge at inconvenient times - such as when there is a tight deadline to deliver a different version of the product.

Pedantically, the other downside of the template options is that they don't comply with the desired "kind of pattern"  i.e. the `if` is not required in

```
 if(VISUALIZE_OUTPUT)
 {
    vis_object.initscene(objects_here);
 }
```

and object lifetimes do not cross scope boundaries.